# Probability of happening function

Tags: c, random, probability

Basically I have a race, in every lap of the race each pilot have 5% probability of crashing.

How can I make a function that test the probability of crashing?

```
//the professor gave us this code but wasn't able to use it/ or understand it

//Returns the value 1 with probability prob. Otherwise, return 0

int probEvent(float prob){
    return prob > ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you ask your professor how it is supposed to be used

Comment: Suggestion (unrelated to your question): use `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Apparently the last class lecture was about [Monte Carlo simulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

Comment: You could use hypothesis testing.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make a function that test the probability of crashing?

Call `probEvent()` a few million times keeping count of the values.

```
unsigned crashes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) crashes += probEvent(0.05);
printf("in 1000000 races there were %u crashes.\n", crashes);
```

Comment: Laps not races.

Comment: Lol, you're right @Strom. In a race with 1000000 laps I'm sure the crash probability increases well past 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out how to use `probEvent()` is to try it out. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int probEvent(float prob){
    return prob > ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (float p = 0.0; p <= 1.01; p += 0.05)
        printf("p: %0.2f\t event:%d\n", p, probEvent(p));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program above calls `probEvent()` with values between 0 and 1, and prints out that value and the result. You'll get different results each time you run it, but there will generally be more 1's toward the end of the run as `p`, the probability of the "event" happening, increases. Here's a sample run:

```
p: 0.00  event:0
p: 0.05  event:0
p: 0.10  event:0
p: 0.15  event:0
p: 0.20  event:1
p: 0.25  event:1
p: 0.30  event:0
p: 0.35  event:1
p: 0.40  event:0
p: 0.45  event:1
p: 0.50  event:1
p: 0.55  event:1
p: 0.60  event:0
p: 0.65  event:1
p: 0.70  event:1
p: 0.75  event:1
p: 0.80  event:1
p: 0.85  event:0
p: 0.90  event:0
p: 0.95  event:1
p: 1.00  event:1
```

If you're still not sure, try running a similar program but always passing in the same `prob` value, and keep track of how the number of 1's compares to `prob`.

Answer (score 0):

The professors function breaks down into the following parts:

Get a random value between 0 and 1.

`((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)`

The comparison `>` operator evaluates to 1 if it is true and 0 if it is false.

The prob variable contains the probability expressed as a number, percent  divided by 100.

For each lap call this function, if it returns 1 the car has crashed.

Comment: Given, pmg's answer, I chose not to give an example since his is accurate.

Answer (score -1):

your function doesn't take into consideration cases that there are more than one pilot.

you ask what is the probability of a crash(one or more).
you must send that function number of pilots.
if you have one pilot it is 5% probability for a crash, if you have two it is
the chance of the first pilot crash (0.05) + if the first one didn't crash then multiply that with the chance of the second pilot to crash.
0.05+(1-0.05)*0.05
[this like might help you to solve it](https://www.edcollins.com/backgammon/diceprob.htm)